# Is it possible to create CAD file from shapefile and also create CAD blocks from the database fields

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, dxf, cad, dwg

I am trying to find out if there is any software or plugin/code that I can bundle that will take a shapefile and export it to a CAD file with CAD blocks generated so our CAD mappers can just move the blocks and finalize the drawing.

For example, I have the following data in the shapefile:

```
lat
long
detail1
detail2
detail3
...
```

I want to have it output:

`detail1
detail2
datail3`

Comment: What software are you using?  If you're using QGIS or another open source product you're probably out of luck, DWG isn't well supported in open source yet, but DXF is.

Comment: I was looking for more of a package the I could include that would allow me to distribute to the user and I could script or write a small program to generate the CAD file.

Answer (score 4):

FME can do Shape to AutoCAD Blocks

[image]

This was modified (for FME 2013) from the original on FMEPedia

http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/Creating-AutoCAD-Blocks-with-FME

Product:
FME Desktop
http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/overview/

Comment: I was looking for more of a package the I could include that would allow me to distribute to the user and I could script or write a small program to generate the CAD file.

Comment: FME server can be used to generate this on a web browser with the user not needing any knowledge of the workflow. http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-server/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Have you try "[Export to CAD](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001n000000)" tool in ArcGIS Toolboxes ?

You can delete lat long in shapefile then use "Export to CAD".

Comment: I was looking for more of a package the I could include that would allow me to distribute to the user and I could script or write a small program to generate the CAD file.